# Awk with php and mysql

Tags: php

I'm trying to use php with awk. The awk command is just to print out the password of a database so i can feed it to the php code to connect to mysql and work the rest of the code.
My awk code looks something like this ( in the php file):

```
$pass = system('awk FS='=' '/Mydbpass/ {print $2}'; file.conf');
```

That code works perfect but it prints the passwod when i open the php file in my browser, how can i make the php mysql read it without having it printed ? I would use include but the `file.conf` doesn't have the password as a variable. If there's any other way to this also please share.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function which returns the output of the command being executed without sending it to the output.

However, it would be most likely much better to read the file directly in your php script and parse it there. Something like:

```
#open the file
$fp = fopen('file.conf', 'r');
if ($fp) {
    while(($line = fgets($fp)) !== false){
        #split the line using = as delimiter
        $cols = array_map(trim, explode('=', $line));

        #do something with the columns
        print_r($cols);

    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) it suits best for this kind of things, no need of using `system` function and [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), you can achieve this in [php](/questions/tagged/php) itself.

```
<?php
         $content=parse_ini_file("your.conf");

         // Your password 
         $password = $content['Mydbpass'];
?>
```

For example if you have input file like below

**Input**

```
$ cat test.conf 
Mydbpass=somesecretpass
Mydbuser=user12344
```

**Output**

```
$ php -r '$content=parse_ini_file("test.conf");print_r($content);'
Array
(
    [Mydbpass] => somesecretpass
    [Mydbuser] => user12344
)
```